# Google Site Map XML code issue

Tags: html, xml, google-search-console

I created an xml sitemap for a site

the following it is

```
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
<url>
<loc>http://hotelriverisland.com</loc>
<loc>http://hotelriverisland.com/services/weddings</loc>
<loc>http://hotelriverisland.com/services/restaurant</loc>
<loc>
http://hotelriverisland.com/services/events-celebrations
</loc>
<loc>http://hotelriverisland.com/services/cabanas</loc>
<loc>http://hotelriverisland.com/food-menus</loc>
<loc>
http://hotelriverisland.com/food-menus/standard-menu
</loc>
<loc>http://hotelriverisland.com/food-menus/grand-menu</loc>
<loc>
http://hotelriverisland.com/food-menus/special-menu
</loc>
<loc>http://hotelriverisland.com/photo-gallery</loc>
<loc>http://hotelriverisland.com/contact-us</loc>
<loc>http://hotelriverisland.com/panorama</loc>
</url>
</urlset>
```

Then I submitted it to GWT (SC) then it gives the following error. Can anyone correct the above code?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KHcEZ.jpg)

Comment: can you paste the error instead of a screenshot?

Comment: Look at the format description. You have too many `<loc>`s for one `<url>` http://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html

Answer (score 0):

If you read it again, it is actually a WARNING rather than an error. Nevertheless, with the given sitemap,  serves no purpose. You could simply remove the  tags to leave the sitemap like this:

```
<urlset>
    <loc></loc>
    <loc></loc>
    etc, etc
</urlset>
```

This should eliminate the warning